# Pass variable to function in R

Tags: r

I cannot understand what I am missing.  My search for an answer did not lead to what I believe is a similar problem.  Any assistance is appreciated!

```
> test
[1] "temp$nitrate"
> mean(temp2$nitrate,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1.280833
> mean(test,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(test, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
>
```

How can I make the mean function read the variable test?

Comment: Here, `test` is a character variable but not a numeric vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want

```
mean(eval(parse(text = test)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too and I think is much more simple :)

```
test <- 1:5
get("test")
```

Comment: It only works for simple variable, doesn't work for expressions. For example: `A = data.frame(a=1); get("A$a")` doesn't work.